# Ifelse condition for timeframes in R

Tags: r, date, if-statement

I have some tricky question to solve, but I somehow can't figure out any answer.

I have the dates and values in mm for rain showers. So what I need to do is to find out, if the amount of 150mm of rain had been exceeded within 3 consecutive days. The data.frame ("rain") I have looks like this.

```
   date amount
1. 1965-07-15     38.85315
2. 1968-08-02     33.22356
3. 1972-08-15     30.90391
4. 1978-08-07     33.34613
5. 1987-08-18     37.85918
6. 1989-07-24     38.23495
7. 1995-07-22     52.46519
8. 1995-07-23     70.29935
9. 1995-07-24     45.11350
```

In the end, I would like to only get the dates where the condition is met. In this case the result should be.

```
7. 1995-07-22     52.46519
8. 1995-07-23     70.29935
9. 1995-07-24     45.11350
```

Now I was trying to think of some if.condition to solve the problem. Unfortunately I can't think of any function in R that would help me. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone had an idea on how to solve this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data:

```
x <- read.table(header=T,
                colClasses=c(date='Date','numeric'),
text="date amount
1965-07-15     38.85315
1968-08-02     33.22356
1972-08-15     30.90391
1978-08-07     33.34613
1987-08-18     37.85918
1989-07-24     38.23495
1995-07-22     52.46519
1995-07-23     70.29935
1995-07-24     45.11350"
                )
```

Find the date spread and sum for each triad:

```
library(zoo)
delta <- rollapply(x$date, 3, FUN=function(x) range(x)[2]-range(x)[1])
sums  <- rollapply(x$amount, 3, FUN=sum)
```

These are the (starting positions) of the rows that you want:

```
delta <= 2 & sums >= 150
## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

And this is the requested subset of the data:

```
w <- which(delta <= 2 & sums >= 150)
x[c(w,w+1,w+2),]
##         date   amount
## 7 1995-07-22 52.46519
## 8 1995-07-23 70.29935
## 9 1995-07-24 45.11350
```